# Why is malloc not allocating the specified memory amount?

Tags: c, printf, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof

I'm learning C dynamic memory allocation and can't figure out why `malloc` or `calloc` are not allocating the amount of memory specified for the struct array, nor for the name char array.

Code example:

```
struct spaceShip{
  long long int distance; // 8 bytes
  int numParts; // 4 bytes
  char *name; // 1 byte
}; // 13 bytes total

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

  int amount=10;
  struct spaceShip *spaceShipArray;

  printf("size of struct spaceShip = %d bytes\n", sizeof(struct spaceShip));

  spaceShipArray = malloc(amount * sizeof(*spaceShipArray));
  printf("size of spaceShipArray = %d bytes\n", sizeof(*spaceShipArray));

  spaceShipArray[0].name = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  printf("size of name char array = %d \n", sizeof(spaceShipArray[0].name));

  free(spaceShipArray);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size of struct spaceShip = 16 bytes //I guess because of the pagination mechanism it takes more? 
size of spaceShipArray = 16 bytes // not ok. should be 160
size of name char array = 4 // not ok. should be 100
```

Comment: `sizeof` cannot give the size of dynamically allocated memory, only the size of the pointer. You need to track the size of dynamically allocated memory yourself.

Comment: It is allocating the amount specified.

Answer (score 2):

For starters to output objects of the type `size_t` you have to use the conversion specifier `%zu`. For example

```
printf("size of struct spaceShip = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(struct spaceShip));
```

These two statements

```
printf("size of struct spaceShip = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(struct spaceShip));
printf("size of spaceShipArray = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(*spaceShipArray));
```

output the same value because the expression `sizeof(*spaceShipArray)` is equivalent to the expression `sizeof(struct spaceShip)`.

That is dereferencing the pointer `spaceShipArray` gives an object of the type `struct spaceShip`. Pointers know nothing whether they point to a single object or a first element of an array.

If you want to output the size of the allocated memory then you should write for example

```
printf("size of spaceShipArray = %zu bytes\n", amount * sizeof(*spaceShipArray));
```

This statement

```
printf("size of name char array = %zu \n", sizeof(spaceShipArray[0].name));
```

outputs the size of a pointer of the type `char *` because it is the type of the expression `spaceShipArray[0].name`.

So the program output is correct.

Take into account that you forgot to free the memory allocated for a character array. For example

```
free( spaceShipArray[0].name );
free(spaceShipArray);
```

Comment: Thx it helped. Should I free also any other variable not assigned by malloc, calloc etc?

Comment: @tec: No - you can only `free` things that have been allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

First output: char* uses 4 bytes on a old computer (32bit) or 8 bytes on a modern computer (64bit) because it is a pointer (not a single char).
Second output: it is correct because it's the size of a single element of the vector (16 byte)
Third output: it is correct because sizeof returns the size of the char pointer (4 bytes on a 32bit computer)